Tengo un error de tipo "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException" en una aplicación WinUI3
Llevo mucho tiempo intentado resolver este problema y no sé qué más hacer. Estoy programando un reseteo de contraseña para una aplicación de escritorio, estoy usando WinUI3 y C#. Ya tengo programada la ventana que, mediante un botón, envía un correo electrónico el cual contiene un link que redirije a otra página de la aplicación en donde se escribiría la nueva contraseña...
El error ocurre cuando se hace click en el link que intenta llevarnos a la nueva página, dice así: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'La aplicación llamó a una interfaz que se aplanó para un diferente subproceso.
Inicialmente, se debe obtener acceso al objeto de aplicación desde el contenedor multiproceso.'
Investigando topé con el manejo de hilos en aplicaciones WinUI y la sugerencia es utilizar DispatcherQueue dentro del método  para manejar operaciones que necesitan ejecutarse en el hilo de la interfaz de usuario. A continuación mostraré el código dentro del archivo App.xaml.cs:
using Assistance.Services;
using Assistance.Views;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Microsoft.Windows.AppLifecycle;
using System;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assistance
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private static DispatcherQueue _dispatcherQueue;
        public static MainWindow MainWindow = new();
        public static RestorePasswordWindow RestorePasswordWindow = new RestorePasswordWindow();

        public IServiceProvider Services { get; private set; }

        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            ConfigureServices();
            _dispatcherQueue = DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();
        }

        private void ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddDbContext<AssistanceDbContext>();
            services.AddScoped<CentroEducativoService>();
            services.AddScoped<AdminSessionService>();
            Services = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        protected override void OnLaunched(Microsoft.UI.Xaml.LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
        {
            if (MainWindow == null)
            {
                MainWindow = new MainWindow();
            }

            var frame = new Frame();
            frame.Navigate(typeof(LoginPage));
            MainWindow.Content = frame;
            MainWindow.Activate();

            var appInstance = AppInstance.GetCurrent();
            var activationArgs = appInstance.GetActivatedEventArgs();

            if (activationArgs.Kind == ExtendedActivationKind.Protocol)
            {
                var protocolArgs = (ProtocolActivatedEventArgs)activationArgs.Data;
                _ = HandleProtocolActivationAsync(protocolArgs.Uri);
            }

        }

        private async static Task HandleProtocolActivationAsync(Uri uri)
        {
            await Task.Yield();

            if (uri.ToString().StartsWith("assistanceapp://resetpassword"))
            {
                var queryParams = new Uri(uri.ToString()).Query;
                var token = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryParams).Get("token");

                var frame = RestorePasswordWindow.Content as Frame;
                if (frame == null)
                {
                    frame = new Frame();
                    RestorePasswordWindow.Content = frame;
                }

                _dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
                {
                    frame.Navigate(typeof(RestorePasswordWindow), token);
                    RestorePasswordWindow.Activate();
                });
                await Task.CompletedTask;

            }
        }

    }
}

Lo que me preocupa es que puse breakpoints en el método HandleProtocolActivationAsync que básicamente prepara la ventana para restablecer la contraseña, asegurando que todo ocurra en el hilo correcto. Pero ese método nunca es tocado, el error ocurre en un archivo autogenerado llamado App.g.i.cs del cual sólo me importan estas líneas de código:

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    XamlCheckProcessRequirements();
    
    global::WinRT.ComWrappersSupport.InitializeComWrappers();
    global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => {
        var context = new global::Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueueSynchronizationContext(global::Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread());
        global::System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
        new App();
    });

El error ya mencionado ocurre en estas líneas:

global::Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Application.Start((p) => {
    var context = new global::Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueueSynchronizationContext(global::Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread());
    global::System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    new App();
});

Si alguien sabe qué puedo hacer, algo que no esté viendo o haciendo mal, agradecería muchísimo un poco de ayuda, llevo más de 3 días en esto...
